# How an I retrieve the same quality of an uploaded image from Prismic

Tags: next.js, graphql, content-management-system, prismic.io

i am trying to get some images with GraphQL , but the problem is I get low quality images ,
this is the query I am using :
[image]
I have tried all these , except `localFile` it returns null . how can I get the same image qualities from this CMS ?

Comment: Hi @Jaacoubi!. If you open that url in the browser, the quality of image is good or bad?

Is bad quality when you add that URL in your next/Image?

Comment: yes it's auto compressed so basically it will lose the some quality .

Comment: That is an answer for question 2 :)?